# Terminology for generalization(?) of telescopic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, telescopic-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n-a_{n+k}).$$

I have been taught to call series of the above form with $k=1$ (and only with $k=1$) "telescopic", so when yesterday my friend who's studyin Economy and Commerce called such series "telescopic" regardless of $k$ I was a bit surprised. Is it common to call all of those simply "telescopic"? Or is there more specific terminology, something like (making this up) "$k$-telescopic" for the above form, and "telescopic" as an abbreviation of "1-telescopic"? Also, does the sequence $a_n$ have a special name, like e.g. *generating sequence* (again, made up by me)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any established terminology, but "$k$-telescopic" seems fine; possibly also calling them a "delay-telescopic series" / "telescopic series with delay $k$" (by analogy with a "delay differential equation") 

I would advise against calling $a_n$ a "generating sequence", as this would inevitably become confused with generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I call any series whose terms cancel a telescoping series.  Of course, that's just my thought on the terminology.

As a related sidenote, we know that if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, then

$$\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)=nL+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)-f(k+n)$$

So for any continuous function, say, $1/x$, we can have non-integer sums using telescoping series:

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k-\frac1{k+n}$$

The last series being defined for non-integer values, such as $n=1/2$.  Of course, such an extension is not unique, though it can be interesting and useful.